# Azure Functions - WindowsAzure.Storage library not working in VS 2017

Tags: function, azure, blob, storage, visual-studio-2017

I have a **full** and **perfectly** working Azure Function within the Azure portale. One part of the function copies blobs from one azure storage container into another one.

I developed the application in VS 2017 and adjusted it within Azure Functions afterwards. In Azure Functions, I extracted my application as a VS 2017 project from Azure Functions in order to make & deploy changes quickly.

I added the current WindowsAzure.Storage 8.4.0 Nuget package to the VS 2017 solution but unfortunately VS Azure Functions does not recognize the package
, see:

[image: screenshot_s1]

I tried to add the Assembly manually but also in that case, I receive that message that the "reference is invalid or unspported".

Any suggestions ?

[image: Overview of the dependecies]

Answer (score 0):

Binding redirect support hasn't been added to Azure Functions yet. You'll need to use a version 7.x Nuget package of WindowsAzure.Storage. If you are able to use version 7.2.1, you won't have any issue, as that's what Azure Functions is currently shipping with.

[Github issue for: Binding redirect support](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/issues/992)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I already managed it differently by re-designing my code and it works perfectly right now. Thanks a lot.